# Why do players get demoted after a server host migration?

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

I created a Tabletop Simulator object with the following script:

```
function onLoad()
    for _, player in ipairs(Player.getPlayers()) do
        if player.promoted == false and player.admin == false then
            player.promote()
        end
    end
end

function onPlayerConnect(player)
    player.promote()
end
```

This seems to work fine when the object is spawned in (`onLoad`), and when new players connect to my session (`onPlayerConnect`). However, after a server host migration (“Give Host”), the players who join the new host are first promoted by the `onPlayerConnect` event but then they get demoted again immediately after. There is no Lua code doing the demotion.

Is there a good solution to this that will keep all players promoted after a server host migration?